# AngularJS Bind $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try to build this directive in angularJS, and I face this problem
which I try to bind to HTML, object property  which its name come from another variable like below example

```
angular.module('ng.box', codeHive.angular.modules)
.directive('boxView', function($compile) {
return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
       var name = 'exampl';
        var htmlTemplate = '<div instance="'+scope[name].innerVal +'"  </div> ';

        var el = angular.element('<div/>');
        el.append(htmlTemplate);
        $compile(el)(scope);
        element.append(el);
    },
  };
})
```

I try to figure out how to bind this object property to the instance attribute in HTML element

```
 var htmlTemplate = '<div instance="'+scope[name].innerVal +'"  </div> ';
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
var htmlTemplate = '<div instance="' + name + '.innerVal"  </div> ';
```

PS. BTW, these lines should be swapped:

```
    element.append(el); // this should be first line
    $compile(el)(scope); // this should be second line
```

The reason is that directives in the template being appended that require other directives on the parent elements will not be able to find them when compiled "offline".